# How to store revision data in database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, version-control, diff

I have a column in a SQL Server database table of type `xml`.

This column data has to be able to store all its previous revisions and some data on each revision.

Since it could be massive files with very few changes it would be silly to store the entire XML string anew on each save. So I'm looking for a way to store only the diffs, in a version-control fashion.

Key features I'm gonna need:

- Save first revision
- On each change, compare this version to last version and store only the diffs, store current version somewhere static to have a handy version
- Rollback

How can I achieve that functionality?

Comment: A member for 5 years and you don't seem to be aware of [help/on-topic] point #4.

Comment: @Shimmy has the world's weirdest "about me" in his profile.  (the "click here to edit" link goes to his blog)

Comment: @KirkWoll yep. u got it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XmlDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302295.aspx) could be useful.  It generates differences (as XML) between two XML documents.

I would also compress (zip, deflate) the data in the column.  You can do compression by hand, but [SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx) also allows compression of columns.